# Append to an existing text file using Photoshop Scripting ( .jsx )

Tags: javascript, photoshop, jsx

I've been unable to find anything similar to my apparently niche case.

I have many .png files, all of which have a rectangular or square transparency on them. I have created a script which finds the bounds, and writes this info to a text file.

Currently the behaviour is that the script creates a single text file for each image, and writes the info I need to that file.

The code is currently as follows:

```
//Create logfile FOLDER on the desktop
var LogFolder = new Folder(Folder.desktop + "/LogFiles/");
if(!LogFolder.exists) LogFolder.create();

//NOTE TO SELF: Would be optimal if appended to single log file
//Create new LOGFILE in the folder using image name
var Loginfo = new File(Folder.desktop + "/LogFiles/" + activeDocument.name.replace(/\.[^\.]+$/, '') + ".txt");
Loginfo.open("w", "TEXT");

//Write the info to the file
Loginfo.write(activeDocument.name.replace(/\.[^\.]+$/, '') + ", " + selectionWidth + ", " + selectionHeight + ", " + selectionTopLeftXOffset + ", " + selectionTopLeftYOffset);

//Close the log
Loginfo.close();
```

.

I've started working at it, but have had no luck making it *append to a single file*:

```
//Create logfile FOLDER on the desktop
var LogFolder = new Folder(Folder.desktop + "/LogFiles/");
if(!LogFolder.exists) LogFolder.create();

//Append to LOGFILE
var Loginfo = new File(Folder.desktop + "/LogFiles/" + "coords.txt");
Loginfo.open("w", "TEXT");

//Write the info to the file
Loginfo.write(activeDocument.name.replace(/\.[^\.]+$/, '') + ", " + selectionWidth + ", " + selectionHeight + ", " + selectionTopLeftXOffset + ", " + selectionTopLeftYOffset + "\r");

//Close the log
Loginfo.close();
```

.

Appending to a single file would make the work that follows the creation of the file significantly easier. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're currently "writing" to the file, not "appending".

- // open() method
- fileExample.open("w"); // write
- fileExample.open("e"); // edit
- fileExample.open("a"); // append

You should be able to change

```
Loginfo.open("w", "TEXT");
```

to

```
Loginfo.open("a", "TEXT");
```

Comment: This worked. I can't believe I missed something so rudimentary! Thanks a lot!